# How to apply grid-gap in display:grid?

Tags: html, css

I applied grid-gap to each of the two classes. However, the gap area is displayed but not white. and the text position is located at the top of each cell. What should I do?

1)

I applied grid-gap to each of the two classes. However, the gap area appears, but **it is not white, but [#96ceb4].** What should I do?

2)

I applied text-align:center, but the text position is located at the top of each cell. I want the **text position to be located in the center of each cell area.** What should I do?

```css
body {
  padding: 50px
}

.container div {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.container div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #96ceb4;
}

.container div:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ff6f69;
}

.container div:nth-child(3) {
  background: #88d8b0;
}

.container div:nth-child(4) {
  background: #ffcc5c;
}

.container div:nth-child(5) {
  background: #96ceb4;
}

.container div:nth-child(6) {
  background: #ff6f69;
}

.one {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.two {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="two">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course it is not white - you gave the `.one` element `background: #96ceb4;`, via that `.container div:nth-child(1)` rule.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I am a beginner in html.^^ I'd be very grateful if anyone could post the corrected code.

Comment: People who always wait for fixed code, will probably _stay_ beginners for a long time. You have been told what the issue is - so why don't you make an attempt to fix it yourself first of all now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the **background color** of the gap area to **white**, add the following **CSS** rule:

```
.container {
background-color: white;
}
```

To **center the text vertically** in each cell, add the following **CSS** rule:

```
.container div {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

**Updated code:**

```css
.container {
background-color: white;
}

 body{padding:50px}
.container div {text-align: center; color:#fff;font-size: 1.5rem;}
.container div:nth-child(1) {background: #96ceb4;}
.container div:nth-child(2) {background: #ff6f69;}
.container div:nth-child(3) {background: #88d8b0;}
.container div:nth-child(4) {background: #ffcc5c;}
.container div:nth-child(5) {background: #96ceb4;}
.container div:nth-child(6) {background: #ff6f69;}

.one {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 100px;
  grid-gap:10px;
}


.two {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 100px;
  grid-gap:10px;
}

.container div {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
To change the background color of the gap area to white, add the following CSS rule:

 <div class="container">
    <div class="one">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>

  <br>

    <div class="two">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```